# Невидимый файл при просмотре проекта unity

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-editor

Хочу добавить кодген в проект. На данным момент частично что то работает через  [InitializeOnLoadMethod] и партиал классы, он приходится создавать новые файлы которые пользователь может видеть. Как можно сделать чтобы в просмоторщике проекта не были видны папки или файлы? Или может как можно сделать кодген +- как это сделано в юнити(где то как то создать файл типо FileName__StructName_12346578.g.cs(хотя если в обычном виндовом проводнике попробовать найти такой файл то его не существует в папке с проектом))?